# SQL Server Express 64 bit prerequisite to include in setup deployment project

Tags: sql-server

Where can I obtain the SQL Server Express 64 bit prerequisite to include in a Visual Studio 2008 setup deployment project.  The prerequisite that comes with Visual Studio 2008 is 32 bit only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no SQL Express x64 based on [this post](http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/x64/archive/2007/08/28/1761.aspx) and it also says on the [express download page that it runs in WOW](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=220549b5-0b07-4448-8848-dcc397514b41&displaylang=en). However, [SQL Server Express 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=58ce885d-508b-45c8-9fd3-118edd8e6fff&DisplayLang=en) does come in a x64 version.